# Share classes vs. swagger generated classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an asp.net/Blazor VS solution with three projects,

1. Shared
2. asp.net core apis
3. Blazor webassembly.

I created bunch of classes in `Shared` project and from the other two projects, made a reference to the `Shared` project.  All is good so far.

Then I used `Swagger UI` to generated stubs for me so I can interact with the remote APIs.  `Swagger UI` created the `Service.cs` and `Contract.cs` which is great.  The problem is that `Contract.cs` has redefined the classes that I have declared in Shared projects under it's own namespace.  Now I don't know which to use and which to import.  If I use my own `Shared` classes, then I won't be able to use the APIs from swagger in `Service.cs` without casting.  If I modify `Contract.cs`, then all my changes will be lost the next time I run `Swagger UI`.

This also resulted in having two `DBContext` - 1) the one I defined and 2) The one that swagger defined. Now every time I want to do something, I also have to use `--context` parameter on the command line to specify which `DBContext` to use.

The question is how can I use my own classes yet use swagger to make life easy in terms of talking to the remote APIs?  What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use Swagger (client side) then you shouldn't reference the Shared project. The swagger claases is what you get/want then.

But you don't need Swagger in Blazor. The opportunity to share DTO classes in Shared is one of the highlights of Blazor.

If you want some help with the boilerplate stuff on the Client then there are options like [refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit). See this [blog](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-refit/) about it.